# STS Spring EntityManager connection 500

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-tool-suite

I'm connecting my project with DB

It is part of Controller

```
public @ResponseBody List<Account> getUserList() {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mysql://kimdg3550.cafe24.com:3306/;user=kimdg3550;password=secret");     
    AccountDaoImpl.entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    return AccountDaoImpl.getAccount();
}
```

I get this error

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named mysql://kimdg3550.cafe24.com:3306/;user=kimdg3550;password=secret
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named mysql://kimdg3550.cafe24.com:3306/;user=kimdg3550;password=secret
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named mysql://kimdg3550.cafe24.com:3306/;user=kimdg3550;password=secret
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named mysql://kimdg3550.cafe24.com:3306/;user=kimdg3550;password=secret
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
>   com.myongjoon.spring.HomeController.getUserList(HomeController.java:41)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.2.RELEASE/8.0.26.B.RELEASE logs.
>
> Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.2.RELEASE/8.0.26.B.RELEASE

I think my DB URL correct.

so what should I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're seriously going to use this approach (which i'm hoping you're not), create a `persistence.xml` file in your classpath that looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And use the *Persistence Unit Name*, in this case `NewPersistenceUnit`, as the parameter of `createEntityManagerFactory`:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
```

In a real world, you should have one `EntityManagerFactory` created at startup time and use that instance to create an `EntityManager`, every time you need one. With your current approach, every request to `getUserList` would create a fresh `EntityManagerFactory` and that's not a good idea.

If you're planning to use Spring Framework, use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` factory bean in order to create an instance of `EntityManagerFactory`.